# Store data as Tables in c# application

Tags: c#, sql

I'm generating one c# app that allows user to calculate multiple factors of one normative. This normative has several tables of different values relations that are requiered in order to calculate all parameters correctly.

I don't know how to store all this data. I started storing them into different .txt files and I add them into the c# project as resources. I wonder if there's a more efficient way to doing it. It is possible to generate a `mdf` and add it into the project so that when I install the application in other PC, it can be used by the application whitout any connection to any central server?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use Sqlite in this case since it doesn't need any server installation or any online connection.

Comment: Research SQLite with C# on the net, look up tutorials. Its a fast self contained SQL database language, to put it in layman terms an engine you can use to store your data locally on your machine.

Comment: If this data doesn't change and it is not expected to change in future and your program just read it sequentially without any kind of search then I would not use a database to store this data.

Comment: what *problem* are you trying to solve? your data requires data; you've implemented a mechanism to load that data. Fine; now; to discuss "more efficient", we need to understand what the problems are in the current mechanism. I don't see how simply switching to a database file helps with that. Is there some processing step that is concerning you? have you considered alternative serialization such as json / xml / protobuf?